# Print job programming not cancelling

Tags: ruby, ssh

I've created a program with will scan through a server specified by the user and output the list of print jobs on that server, from there it will output all jobs older then 2016, and `gsub` down to the job ID number.

Then what it's suppose to do is cancel the job, but what it's doing is saying:

```
Cancelling job: 829116
cancel: cancel-job failed: Job #829116 does not exist!
Cancelling job: 795259
cancel: cancel-job failed: Job #795259 does not exist!
Cancelling job: 795260
cancel: cancel-job failed: Job #795260 does not exist!
Cancelling job: 797216
cancel: cancel-job failed: Job #797216 does not exist!
Cancelling job: 797217
cancel: cancel-job failed: Job #797217 does not exist!
```

When it does exist, if I go to the specific server and run a `prt_jobs` the job pops up.. example:

```
#On the server I ran prt_jobs
cdprt11-829116          dij             244736   Mon Aug 24 06:07:12 2015
closing_2-795259        dlc             228352   Tue Jul 28 13:43:08 2015
closing_2-795260        dlc             228352   Tue Jul 28 13:44:05 2015
closing_2-797216        tkb             286720   Wed Jul 29 13:56:27 2015
closing_2-797217        tkb             250880   Wed Jul 29 13:56:41 2015
```

Can anyone tell me why it's not cancelling the jobs specified?

Source:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'etc'

class PrintJobs

 HOST = ARGV[0]
 USERNAME = Etc.getlogin
 PASSWORD = nil

 def scan_for_jobs
   check_jobs = Net::SSH.start(HOST, USERNAME, :password => PASSWORD) do |ssh|
     cmd = "prt_jobs"
     info = ssh.exec!(cmd)
     if info == nil
       puts "No print jobs on server #{HOST}"
     else
       res = info.split("\n").reject {|line| line.match(/\s+2016/s+/)}.join("\n")
       puts res
       print "Process into kill que: "
       input = STDIN.gets.chomp.upcase
       if input == "YES"
         kill_que(check_jobs, res)
       else
         exit 1
       end
     end
   end
 end

 def kill_que(check_jobs, res)
   puts "Loading jobs into kill que.."
   column = 0
   job_ids = res.lines.map { |job| job.split(/\s+/)[0] }.each do |task_id|
     kill_jobs(task_id)
   end
 end

 def kill_jobs(task_id)
    id_to_strip = task_id.gsub(/\-/," ")
    column = 1
    stripping_id = id_to_strip.lines.map { |task| task.split(/\s+/)[1] }.each do |id|
      id.strip
      puts "Cancelling job: #{id}"
      `sudo cancel #{id}`
      # puts id
    end
  end
end

test = PrintJobs.new
test.scan_for_jobs
```

Comment: You execute your `sudo cancel #{id}` locally. You probably want to execute it on the remote server using your SSH connection instead.

Comment: You should give another argument to the  `kill_jobs` method so that it will run on the SSH connection..

Comment: @HolgerJust Could you make an answer on how I would do that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed in comments to question, `cancel` command is issued on local server and not on the remote server.  You need to pass `ssh` object to `kill_jobs` and execute the command on `ssh` connection.

**Step 1**:  Pass `ssh` to `kill_que` method.

```
   if input == "YES"
     kill_que(ssh, check_jobs, res)  # *** Pass ssh object
```

**Step 2**: Update `kill_que` method to use `ssh` object

```
def kill_que(ssh, check_jobs, res)
   puts "Loading jobs into kill que.."
   column = 0
   job_ids = res.lines.map { |job| job.split(/\s+/)[0] }.each do |task_id|
     kill_jobs(ssh, task_id)  # *** Pass ssh to kill_jobs
   end
end
```

**Step 3**: Use `ssh` in `kill_jobs`

```
def kill_jobs(ssh, task_id)
    id_to_strip = task_id.gsub(/\-/," ")
    column = 1
    stripping_id = id_to_strip.lines.map { |task| task.split(/\s+/)[1] }.each do |id|
      id.strip
      puts "Cancelling job: #{id}"
      ssh.exec!("sudo cancel #{id}")  # *** Issue this command via ssh
      # puts id
    end
end
```